# In PowerShell how can I compare objects with different properties and retain the original properties from the Reference Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare two objects in PowerShell. I would like to compare on one property of the object and retain all the properties of the original object. I have the following Objects:

```
UserID ID
aaa    111
aab    112
aac    113
zaa    211
zab    212

UserID
aaa
aab
aac
```

I would like my output to be:

```
UserID ID
zaa    211
zab    212
```

I've tried to use `Compare-Object` with no luck.  It seems I either lose the ID column in the comparison or it compares the entire row instead of just the UserID property.  How can I accomplish this comparison?

```
$ObjectsToDelete = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DirectoryItemsToSync -DifferenceObject $CurrentUserPropertyValues
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$A
UserID ID
------ -- 
aaa    111
aab    112
aac    113
zaa    211
zab    212

$B
UserID
------
aaa
aab
aac

$A | where {$B.UserID -notcontains $_.userid}

UserID ID 
------ -- 
zaa    211
zab    212
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that `$DirectoryItemsToSync` is the upper list with with both `UserId` and `ID`.

Use the [`Where-Object Cmdlet`](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ee177028):

```
$DirectoryItemsToSync | Where {($CurrentUserPropertyValues | Select -Expand UserID) -NotContains $_.UserID}
```